# Converting datetime character vector into date-time format

Tags: r, datetime, format, posixct, strptime

I have tried to convert below character vector into date-time format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") but was unable to successfully convert mid-night time-stamp. If the vector contains both date(mid-night 00:00:00) as well as date-times in the same operation. Any handy option available to do this. Please ignore character length and paste option. Thanks.

```
dttime=c()
dttime=c("2021-08-03 11:59:59", "2021-08-03 12:59:59", "2021-08-03", 
"2021-08-03 16:59:59")
strptime(dttime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2021-08-03 11:59:59 IST" "2021-08-03 12:59:59 IST" NA "2021-08-03 16:59:59 IST 
as.POSIXct(dttime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2021-08-03 11:59:59 IST" "2021-08-03 12:59:59 IST" NA "2021-08-03 16:59:59 IST"
format(dttime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2021-08-03 11:59:59" "2021-08-03 12:59:59" "2021-08-03         " "2021-08-03 16:59:59
```

Desired output is:

```
dttime
[1] "2021-08-03 11:59:59" "2021-08-03 12:59:59" "2021-08-03 00:00:00" "2021-08-03 16:59:59
```

Any other available existing method.

```
dttime[nchar(dttime)<19]=paste(dttime[nchar(dttime)<19],"00:00:00")
> dttime
 [1] "2021-08-03 11:59:59" "2021-08-03 12:59:59" "2021-08-03 00:00:00" "2021-08-03 16:59:59"
```

Comment: Try `format()`...i.e. `format(dttime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. In general the 00:00:00 is there but it simply doesn't print

Comment: @Sotos How do we make sure that its "00:00:00" before writing it into any schema or pushing it as csv file. Its (format(dttime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[3]=="2021-08-03 00:00:00") actually returning false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as_datetime` function from lubridate package

```r
library(lubridate)
#> Warning: package 'lubridate' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
dttime = c("2021-08-03 11:59:59", "2021-08-03 12:59:59",
           "2021-08-03", "2021-08-03 16:59:59")
as_datetime(dttime, tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "2021-08-03 11:59:59 UTC" "2021-08-03 12:59:59 UTC"
#> [3] "2021-08-03 00:00:00 UTC" "2021-08-03 16:59:59 UTC"
```

You can change the timezone into another timezone, see `?as_datetime`